Como acceder a los miembros del enumerador DateOfWeek
Hola tengo el siguiente problema en una tabla guardo el numero correspondiente al día de la semana
ejemplo si hoy es lunes:
byte Hoy = (byte)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek; --> entonces hoy=1

No logro hacer el paso inverso es decir acceder al enum con el valor y obtener el name, es decir 'Lunes'
Alguna sugerencia? gracias

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Si lo deseas en español usa un Dictionary. Me parece que sería más corto usando : string diaEnEspañol = fechaHoy.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("es-ES"));

DayOfWeek es una enumeración (enum) definida como:
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6
}

1.- De enum a número
Puedes convertir a cualquier tipo numérico, siempre que la enumeración no tenga un valor fuera del rango. Por ejemplo, si usas byte la enumeración no debe tener un valor que sea mayor a 255 ni menor a 0
byte numero = (byte)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

2.- De enum a string
Entregará el nombre de la enumeración
string nombre = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString(); //ej: monday

3.- De número a enum
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)2; // Tuesday 

4.- De string a enum
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = Enum.Parse<DayOfWeek>("monday");

O de manera "más segura"
//                                      ↓ Ignora mayuscas y minusculas      
if (Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>("mOnDay", true, out var result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error al convertir");
}

5.- Obtener el nombre del día según el idioma del sistema
string dia = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetDayName(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek); // jueves


Puedes usar DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek (Constante enumerada que indica el día de la semana de este valor DateTime) para obtenber un valor que indica el día de la semana y mediante un Dictionary obtener su texto:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class WeekDays {
  static void Main() {

    byte hoy = (byte)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek; 
     //Console.WriteLine($"El día de hoy : \"{hoy}\"");
        var diasSemana = new Dictionary<byte, string>
        {
            { 0, "Domingo" },
            { 1, "Lunes" },
            { 2, "Martes" },
            { 3, "Miércoles" },
            { 4, "Jueves" },
            { 5, "Viernes" },
            { 6, "Sábado" }
        };

        if (diasSemana.TryGetValue(hoy, out string dia)){
            Console.WriteLine($"El día de hoy es: \"{dia}\"");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Error, no se pudo obtener el día de la semana.");
        }
    
    
  }
}

Salida:
El día de hoy es: "Jueves"


Si lo deseas en inglés, usa simplemente:
   string dayName = Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek),  (byte)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
    Console.WriteLine($"El día de hoy es: \"{dayName}\"");

